# return type required in Java

Tags: java, return

```
public Course(String cat,String breed,int age) {
    this.Cat = cat;
    this.Breed = breed;
    this.Age = age; }
```

what would be the return type of this code?

Hey everyone! I've never taken Java before and it's required, so I need to complete this assignment. Please help me with this very simple question. Thank you so so sooo much in advance!

Comment: That looks like a constructor. Constructors don't have a return type.

Comment: How do i fix this? :/ it says "invalid method declaration; return type required"

Comment: You need to post a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Course cat = new Course("cat", "tabby", 7);
    if(cat.isTabby()) {
        System.out.println("Orange");

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Other color");
    }
 }
  static class Course {
    String Cat;
    String Breed;
    int Age;
    public Course(String cat,String breed,int age) {
    this.Cat = cat;
    this.Breed = breed;
    this.Age = age; 
        }
        public boolean isTabby() {
            if(Breed=="tabby") {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no return type, as it is a constructor. Constructors are used to
"construct things", such as

```
Course cat = new Course("cat","tabby",6);
```

And normally people add functions in the class to operate on this, as I show above.

Answer (score -1):

This is a constructor, which is used to instantiate Objects. It does not have a return type.

Comment: How do i fix this? :/ it says "invalid method declaration; return type required"